# Create topology PostgreSQL break line

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am using pgRouting on PostgreSQL 9.6, and for pgRouting. I need to run pg_createToplogy on the roads data, but it splits the roads at intersections and add source and target in respective columns.

Is there a way to avoid the breaking at intersection and populate Source and target column using pg_createTopology?

Answer (score 3):

`pgR_createTopology` does not split anything. It however set the Source and Target, in addition to creating a point at the segment end nodes. See the [doc](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_createTopology.html#pgr-create-topology). `pgr_nodeNetwork` would split the lines at intersection though.
Setting the source/target is a mandatory step as the route computation relies on it to find the path between two points. In the [doc](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_nodeNetwork.html#pgr-node-network)  about `pgr_nodeNetwork` there is useful picture of the network with/without the nodes at intersections. Read it to understand why you need them.